# php artisan tinker >> schema drop(' ') causing error

Tags: laravel

At first I got error in::
php artisan migrate:rollback

> [ErrorException]
>       Undefined index: 2016_09_29_105926_create_author_table

to solve it I tried tinker.. but it didn't work

```
php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 5.6.8 ΓÇö cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> schema::drop('larw')
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'schema' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @Komal thnk u.. i got it :)

Comment: @shefalisharma You need to show us the contents of the migration file. Somewhere in there you've used an array index that doesn't exist. You should try capitalizing `Schema`, as well.

Answer (score -1):

artisan need to run:

```
php artisan optimize
```